# How to refer to the current path in this recursive find and replace?

Tags: bash, git, gitignore

**Disclaimer**: (off-topic warning) This is **not** about outputting the list of ignored files actually detected in the repo. This is about ignored *paths*, even when no file is in fact matching one of these paths.

---

**Context**: I'm attempting to write a git alias to "flatten" all .gitignore patterns recursively and output a list of paths *as they're seen from the top level*.

What I mean with an example:

```
├─ .git
├─ .gitignore
└─ dir1
    ├─ .gitignore
    ├─ file1.txt
    └─ file2.txt
```

With these contents in `.gitignore` files:

```
# (currently pointing at top-level directory)
$ cat .gitignore
some_path

$ cat dir1/.gitignore
yet_another_path
*.txt
```

I try to have an alias to output something along the lines of

```
$ git flattened-ignore-list
some_path
dir1/yet_another_path
dir1/*.txt
```

---

**What do I have so far?**

I know I can search for all .gitignore files in the repo with

```
find . -name ".gitignore"
```

which in this case would output

```
.gitignore
dir1/.gitignore
```

So I've tried to combine this with `cat` to get their contents (either of these work)

```
find . -name ".gitignore" | xargs cat
# or
cat $(find . -name ".gitignore")
```

with this result:

```
some_path
yet_another_path
*.txt
```

which is technically expected but unfortunately unhelpful for what I am trying to achieve. So to (at last!) arrive at my actual question:

**How can I, for each result of `find`, refer to the current path?** (in order to eventually prepend it to the line)

---

**Note for people suspecting an XY problem** : It *might* be the case, my approach might just be naive here, but maybe not, I'm unsure. For example I didn't consider complex cases where nested .gitignore files could refer to upper-levels, or special syntax with `**`. I've stuck to very simple structures for now, so in case you see a flaw and/or can suggest a totally different way to achieve the same goal, I'll of course be happy to hear about it also.

Answer (score 2):

> I try to have an alias to output something along the lines of
>
> ```
> $ git flattened-ignore-list
> some_path
> dir1/yet_another_path
> dir1/*.txt
> ```

Unfortunately, this approach is naive (and perhaps doomed, but maybe not) because entries in `.gitignore` files are a bit complicated.

The simple answer to the simple question you asked is to use something that prepends the directory name, relative to the top level.  Since `find` never outputs unnecessarily-complicated names, you can do this with direct string processing:

> ```
> .gitignore
> dir1/.gitignore
> ```

tells you that when reading the first file, prepend nothing, and when reading the second, prepend `dir1` to each entry.  Doing this in shell is a little tricky, but bash has the tools needed: you just get the line minus the `/.gitignore` at the end, either using regexp replacement or just removing 11 characters (if I counted right) from anything that has a slash in it or isn't the literal 10-character string `.gitignore`.  Grab the directory off the part before the `/.gitignore` name and use `sed` or `awk` to insert it, and a slash, in front of non-comment entries (and remember to handle `!` entries a little differently).

You are probably better off handling the top level `.gitignore` separately–you can just copy it straight through, adding a final newline if necessary—and then dealing with subdirectory `.gitignore`s in a different code path.

Note that a subdirectory `.gitignore` *cannot* refer to something above it: nothing in `dir1/.gitignore` can change whether `./foo` or `dir2/foo` is ignored or not.  So that part is not a problem.

The part that *is* a problem is that, in `dir1`, the entry:

```
*.txt
```

implies that the top level should not only ignore untracked `dir1/*.txt` files, but also ignore `dir1/sub/*.txt` files, `dir1/sub/sub2/*.txt`, and so on.  However, a `dir1` entry reading:

```
sub/*.txt
```

means that the top level should ignore only untracked `dir1/sub/*.txt` files, without ignoring any `dir1/sub/sub2/*.txt` files!

You may be able to salvage this with yet more code: while reading a subdirectory `.gitignore`, check to see if there are embedded slashes in any given line.  An *embedded* slash is one that is *not* the final slash, because final slashes are removed for this particular differentiation.

- If the entry contains an embedded slash, it applies only to the full-path-relative-to-the-subdirectory.  You can therefore add `dir1/` in front and be done, e.g.:

  ```
  dir1/foo/*.txt
  ```
- If the entry does not contain an embedded slash, it applies to the subdirectory and all of its nested sub-subdirectories.  You will need to allow for any arbitrary number of subdirectories.  This *might* be correct, but it's quite untested:

  ```
  dir1/*.txt
  dir1/**/*.txt
  ```

  (In theory `**/` should also match the empty list of subdirectories, so only the second line *should* be needed, but in practice I have seen this not happen for some cases.  I do not recall whether this was in other pathspecs, `.gitignore` files, or both.)

In general, most `.gitignore` entries seem not to contain embedded slashes, so any successful script you write will probably produce a nearly double-length "flattened" ignore file, compared to its input length.

Comment: I'll have to digest that and work on it more. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can produce a complete list of ignore patterns, with directory prefix like this:

```sh
#!usr/bin/env sh

find \
  . \
  -type f \
  -name '.gitignore' \
  -printf '%h\n' \
  | while IFS= read -r dir_name; do
    printf \
      "${dir_name}/%s\\n" \
      $(
        sed \
          --silent \
          '/^[^#[:space:]]/p' \
          "$dir_name/.gitignore"
      )
  done
```

The above code will just list all patterns found in `.gitignore` files across directories, and add the directory as prefix of each pattern.

It does not reflect `gitignore` syntax and behavior that is described here in git documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: That's great, thanks to you. However, I have to add that my shell knowledge is still very limited, so I'll have this follow-up : to execute the script (I'm on Windows, I use Git for Window's bash-capable terminal, which allows for .bashrc and functions there) I have to put it in a function in my `.bashrc`?

Comment: @RomainValeri my code is just a sample of how you can get a list of patterns. It still is not a flattened `.gitignore` as it prefixes all patterns with the directory of the `.gitignore` file. Patterns like `*.bak` witch would ignore files in every directory, becomes prefixed with `./dir/*.bak` and from that would work only from the actual `./dir/` only. So there is till work ToDo to make it produce a flattened `.gitignore`